# Python define variables and import variables in different python files

Tags: python, python-2.7

In my project I have 4 python files:

file1.py, file2.py file3.py, file4.py

test_list1 list  I want to define globally this should accessible to all the files.

I mean,

if i will define list  in file1.py

```
 test_list1 = []
```

and I am importing file1.py to file2.py, file3.py and file4.py

I need to append values to list test_list1 from file2.py , file3.py and file4.py

The execution of the script flow is file2.py followed by file3.py and followed by file4.py. and again file 2 is going to access

what is the best way to define variable this kind of different files.

I know my English language  is worst . Please let me know if not understand the question properly.

Comment: import all files into a main file, and you can define test_list1 in the main file , then pass that variable to other functions from other files

Comment: ... don't do this. Imported modules should not assume anything about the module calling them (that leads to headaches). Have the calling module pass it as a parameter instead.

Comment: @stack mail file is promising could you please give example or any link to refer and @ Hugh please provide example or docs

Answer (score 0):

I think your file1.py is your main module and you define your `test_list1 = []` there, 
If you use this list in functions, you can pass this through function parameter, like `your_fuction(test_list1)` in this case the best way is that you import only the function that you will use in your file1.py, like `from file2 import your_function, your_function2`, and when you were in file2.py and you use some function from file3.py do the same, `from file3 import your_file3_function`.